# Confusion surrounding notation in proof of central limit theorem

Tags: mathematical-statistics, random-variable

In john rice Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis we find a proof about the central limit theorem.

Let $X_{1} , X_{2}...$ be a sequence of independent random variables having variance $\sigma^{2}$ and the commmon distribution function F and moment generating function $M$ defined in a neighborhood of zero. Let

$S_{n} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}X_{i}$

Then:

$\lim\limits_{n \longrightarrow \infty}P (\frac{S_{n}}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} \le x) = \Phi(x)$

Proof:

Let $Z_{n} = \frac{S_{n}}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}$

Since $S_{n}$ is a sum of independent random variables:

$M_{S_{n}}(t) = [M(t)]^{n}$

$M_{Z_{n}}(t) = [M(\frac{t}{\sigma \sqrt{n}})]^{n}$

$M(s)$ has a taylor series expansion about zero.

$M(s) = M(0) + s M'(0) + \frac{1}{2}s^{2}M''(0) + \epsilon_{s}$

but I don't know what $M(s)$ means? Particularly what does the $s$ signify?

Comment: $M$ is a moment generating function as it says on line 2 of your post, and $s=\frac{t}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}$ is the argument of $M$.

Comment: So $M(s) = M_{Z_{n}}(t)$?

Comment: $M(s)$ is the moment generating function for all of the iid random variables $X_i$. They all have the same moment generating function. $s$ is a variable, but since $M$ is only assumed to exist in a neighborhood of $0$, it must be assumed that $s$ is inside that neighborhood for the statement to make sense. Probably later in the proof, for a given $t$ you will take $n$ sufficiently large so that the $s$ as defined in the first comment will be in the region where $M$ is defined.